# is card emulation implemented through libnfc-nxp library in Android?

Tags: android, nfc

I know NFC functionality is implemented in libnfc-nxp library in Android. So, does it mean that card emulation functionality is defined and implemented there, too? To be more specific, I have a phone in card emulation mode, my CPR 40.30 reader, however, cannot read nor write to the card emulated in it, as it doesn't even recognize the type of transponder.Although it can read the UID when touching the phone to it. When I asked someone for help, he asked me if I wanted to work with libnfc-nxp library.This is why I'm curious about this library and to know if I can modify it so that I can access card emulated in secure element. Any help will be very grateful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual card emulation is done by the embedded Secure Element in the NFC chip in Android NFC devices that use libnfc-nxp as the driver library. The library itself is only used to turn card emulation on or off.

Comment: Thanks. Still, why reader cannot connect to the secure element?should I modify something or do something special to have my reader to authenticate or identify the card emulated in secure element?I know JSR 177 API is used to access SE through applications in J2ME based mobile phones. However my mobile OS is Android. Do I have to deal with JSR 177 yet?

Comment: And, actually I also need to use this functionality of libnfc-nxp (turning on the card emulation mode on and off), can you give me some advice in this context too?

Comment: I found out that the reason the reader couldn't connect to SE was that we didn't send APDU commands to the SE from reader. So, I guess my first question is answered. My second question remains unanswered however. So, I will be grateful if you can help me with it

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the UID your reader is receiving from the phone? I do have the doubt that your reader is detecting an NFC target (and not the emulated card). If the ID starts with 0x80 (or ends -- depending on the byte order), it is the anticollision ID of an NFC Target.